# Easiest book on Analysis and Topology.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request

I have searched a lot for some book to study real analysis and then topology from. I got many results, but My understanding of analysis is weaker than algebra and same with topology. I got confused in Bartle for analysis and Munkres for topology while being taught in college so that is no good to me.

I want to pick up the easiest text available with lots of examples and go through them. Then move back to Munkres etc. Are there any books. Please someone with experience suggest me some book I can buy and start reading ASAP. I have qualifying exams to clear after two months. Please help.

**P.S.-** in Real Analysis I have downloaded Howie's Real Analysis ebook and it looked easier than other texts, should I buy it, or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest real analysis book is probably Ross' Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus.

Munkres is also probably one of the easiest point-set topology books. Alan Hatcher has an old [list](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/topologybooks.pdf) of topology books but I don't think you're going to find anything easier.

Both real analysis and topology are *hard* subjects, and no book is going to make them easy. You're going to have to do some struggling through them.

Comment: It's Allen not Alan!

Answer (score 1):

I have bought Howie and it is very accessible I doubt you could find an easier book - it also covers most of real analysis. However, Bartle is a good book to teach or learn so could you be more explicit with your issues?